# Quartiles in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have payment amounts like so -

```
id      payment
13743   2090439.11
1750327 514457.45
124049  1583176.43
2323    948421.5
1106    2334.2
```

How do I divide records like this into quartiles. It doesn't have to be perfect. For example, the data in the question would transform like so -

```
id      payment     Quartile
13743   2090439.11  Q4
1750327 514457.45   Q2
124049  1583176.43  Q3
2323    1232336.5   Q3
1106    2334.2      Q1
```

Ids 124049 and 2323 are given the same quartile because those payment values are close together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ntile` function :

```
select * , ntile(4) over (order by payment) as Quartile
from data
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=899cf94c71557d62a89f73f13c0db971)*